# Select appropriate tr in table - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select the tr tag containing USDTRY value in its second td and change its value with TRYUSD using jquery?

```
<table class="k-selectable" cellspacing="0" role="grid" data-role="selectable">
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" data-uid="9d1c0ae7-ec5d-4377-ad61-9eace8158802">
        <td role="gridcell">
            <img src="/Images/up.png">
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell">USDTRY</td>
        <td role="gridcell">1.30514</td>
        <td role="gridcell">1.30527</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="k-alt" role="row" data-uid="0ff48da9-2019-4cf8-b631-a09c3ce98d63">
    <tr role="row" data-uid="2c9ae0ba-c744-4bbb-9a23-fd15a3b65b6c">
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this snippet:

```
$('td[role="gridcell"]:contains("USDTRY")').text('TRYUSD');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/unudup/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You want to narrow down your selection as far as possible using regular selectors, then you can use the [`:contains` psuedoselector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to search for your text:

```
$('table.k-selectable td:contains("USDTRY")').text('TRYUSD');
```

Comment: can be narrowed down to `tr td:contains` ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not a perfect solution, but try this:

```
$('table.k-selectable tr td').each(function() {
     if($(this).text() === 'USDTRY') {
         $(this).text('TRYUSD');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(selector).find("tr:contains('USDTRY ')");
```

or

```
$('tableId td:contains("USDTRY")').text('TRYUSD ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the contains selector:

```
$('td:contains("USDTRY")').html('TRYUSD ');
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to find `tr`..just find `td` with that text using `filter()` and replace

```
 $('td').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == "USDTRY";
 }).text('TRYUSD');
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/P5UGt/)